# CodeSignal problem. I want to complete the code

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I have the following problem. The function `printMatrix`

Receive an matrix for example:

```
matrix:
[[0,1,1,2], 
 [0,5,0,0], 
 [2,0,3,3]]
```

The code that I must use is the following:

```
// Definition for arrays:
// typedef struct arr_##name {
//   int size;
//   type *arr;
// } arr_##name;
//
// arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) {
//   arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
//   return a;
// }
//
//
void printMatrix(arr_arr_integer matrix) 
{

}
```

As a clue they give me that the number of columns and rows can be determined in the following way.

```
  int columns = matrix.arr->size; //No.columns
  int rows = matrix.size; //No.rows
  
  //Or

  int columns = matrix.arr[0].size; //No.columns
  int rows = matrix.size; //No.rows
```

My question lies in how is the rest of the code written so that the previous tracks can work?

That is, for this to work within the function `printMatrix`

What should you add or modify in your code for the above methods to work?

```
typedef struct arr_arr_integer {
   int size;
   type *arr;
} arr_arr_integer;

arr_arr_integer alloc_arr_arr_integer(int len) {
arr_arr_integer a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
   return a;
}

void printMatrix(arr_arr_integer matrix) 
{
   int columns = matrix.arr->size; //No.columns
   int rows = matrix.size; //No.rows
   
   //print matrix?
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   //input matrix?

   printMatrix(arr_arr_integer matrix)

   return 0;
}
```

**I repeat. I must use this code strictly**

```
int columns = matrix.arr->size; //No.columns
int rows = matrix.size; //No.rows
```

The problem is that when I try to use those tracks I get the following compilation error.

```
error: request for member 'size' in something not a structure or union
```

Comment: This is duplicate of your question from 6 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63767458/fill-an-matrix-with-the-following-structure-in-c

Comment: I was not very clear in the previous post, so I decided to make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The function `alloc_arr_integer` allocates a 1D array of integers.

If you need a 2D array, you'll have to call the function multiple times.

Something like:

```
arr_integer my2Darray[rows];

// Create the 2D array
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    my2Darray[i] = alloc_arr_integer(columns);
    assert(my2Darray[i].arr != NULL);
}

// Initialize the 2D array
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
    {
        my2Darray[i].arr[j] = i * 1000 + j;
    }
}
```

Putting it together:

```
int main(void)
{
    int rows = 3;
    int columns = 5;
    
    arr_integer my2Darray[rows];

    // Create the 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        my2Darray[i] = alloc_arr_integer(columns);
        assert(my2Darray[i].arr != NULL);
    }

    //Initialize the 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
        {
            my2Darray[i].arr[j] = (i + 1) * 1000 + j;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", my2Darray[i].arr[j]);    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 
2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 
3000 3001 3002 3003 3004
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I would like to know is how the `matrix.arr-> size` part works.

Supposedly those are to know the number of columns, but I don't understand how the structure should be written for this `matrix.arr-> size` to work

Comment: @A.m.Jacome It's unclear what you are asking. I don't see any `matrix` structure in your question

Comment: Thank You dor answer. I just edited the post. perhaps now it is clearer. An apology.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume memory allocation for 'matrix' is done somewhere else.

```
void printMatrix(arr_arr_integer matrix) 
{
    int rows = matrix.size;
    int columns = matrix.arr.size;
    int i, j = 0;

    /*print array*/
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    {
         for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
             printf("%d ", a.arr[i].arr[j]);
         printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was practicing for code signal and I wrote my own functions to stablish the arrays. They are as shown below (even though this is a little bit too late maybe).

```
typedef struct arr_integer
{
    int size;
    int *arr;
} arr_integer;

typedef struct arr_arr_integer
{
    int size;
    arr_integer *arr;
} arr_arr_integer;

arr_integer alloc_arr_integer(int size)
{
    arr_integer *pointer;
    pointer = malloc(sizeof(arr_integer));
    pointer->size = size;
    pointer->arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    return *pointer;
}

arr_arr_integer alloc_arr_arr_integer(int size)
{
    arr_arr_integer *pointer;
    pointer = malloc(sizeof(arr_arr_integer));
    pointer->size = size;
    pointer->arr = malloc(size * sizeof(arr_integer));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        pointer->arr[i].arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    }

    return *pointer;
}
```